# Mapping list to Map not working

Tags: groovy

I have a map

> ["name1":["field1":value1, "field2":value2, "field3":value3], 
>   "name2":["field1":value4, "field2":value5, "field3":value6], 
>   "name3":["field1":value7, "field2":value8, "field3":value9]]

and a list

> [name1, name3]

I wanted a result as

> ["name1":["field1":value1, "field2":value2, "field3":value3], 
>   "name3":["field1":value7, "field2":value8, "field3":value9]]

The code used

```
result = recomendationOffers.inject( [:] ) { m, v ->
                if( !m[ v ] ) {
                    m[ v ] = []
                }
                m[ v ] << tariffRecMap[ v.toString() ]
                m
                }
```

Now the datatype of the name1 changed from Varchar2(35) to number(10).

I expected the same logic to work but it is not working and I am getting values

> ["name1":[null], "name3":[null]]

also the value such as 1000000959 is displayed as 1.000000959E9, is this making any difference ?

posting the original values

When I was handling with **string**, it looked as below

> ["FBUN-WEB-VIRGIN-10-24-08":["FIXEDLN_ALLOWANCE":0.0,
>   "OFFER_VERSION_ID":1.000013082E9, "OFFER_TYPE_DESC":"Contract",
>   "OFFER_NAME":"PM_V 10 50+250 CA", "SMS_ALLOWANCE":250.0,
>   "VM_TARIFF_FLAG":"N", "IPHONE_IND":"N", "OFFER_MRC":10.5,
>   "ALLOWANCE08":0.0, "DATA_ALLOWANCE":524288.0, "BB_IND":"N",
>   "CONTRACT_TERM":24.0, "OFFER_CODE":"FBUN-WEB-VIRGIN-10-24-08",
>   "ONNET_TEXT_ALLOWANCE":0.0, "VOICE_ALLOWANCE":50.0,
>   "MMS_ALLOWANCE":0.0, "ONNET_ALLOWANCE":0.0],

Now after the database datatype changed to **number** from varchar it looks as below where **the value in DB is 1000010315**

> [1.000010315E9:["FIXEDLN_ALLOWANCE":0.0,
>   "OFFER_VERSION_ID":1.000010315E9, "OFFER_TYPE_DESC":"Sup Voice",
>   "OFFER_NAME":"VIP - 35 c", "SMS_ALLOWANCE":60000.0,
>   "VM_TARIFF_FLAG":"N", "IPHONE_IND":"N", "OFFER_MRC":35.0,
>   "ALLOWANCE08":45000.0, "DATA_ALLOWANCE":2.147483648E9, "BB_IND":"N",
>   "CONTRACT_TERM":24.0, "OFFER_CODE":"FBUN-MVP-WEB-VIRGIN-35-24-20",
>   "ONNET_TEXT_ALLOWANCE":0.0, "VOICE_ALLOWANCE":45000.0,
>   "MMS_ALLOWANCE":0.0, "ONNET_ALLOWANCE":0.0]

Answer (score 1):

> Now the datatype of the name1 changed from Varchar2(35) to number(10) ... also the value such as 1000000959 is displayed as 1.000000959E9, is this making any difference ?

Yes, all the difference in the world.  That means you're converting a `Double` (most likely) to a `String`, and as the String `"1000000959"` is not equal to `"1.000000959E9"`, you don't get a match.

Not sure from the question which bits are doubles and which bits are Strings...  Maybe you could expand with an actual example?

Also, your inject method can be replaced with:

```
def result = tariffRecMap.subMap( recomendationOffers )
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the response. Does this work for 1.5.6 version? or shall I use some conversion to string ?

Comment: @user3433227 Have you changed username? `subMap` has been there [since groovy 1.0 apparently](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#subMap(java.util.Collection)).  I'm not sure what you have, or what you need as the question has nothing resembling doubles in it, it's just a working example

Comment: Hi Tim, I could not access my previous account :-( so had to create a new one. I will try from my end and will get back to you if I am not successful in my attempts. Cheers

Comment: Hi Tim, how do I convert 1.000000959E9 to 1000000959 in groovy? May be I will edit my question with my values ...

Comment: Hi Tim, edited the question with original values, please have a look

Comment: Are the keys `Double` instances, or strings representing doubles? You shouldn't use doubles as keys for a map

Comment: I think they are the string representation of doubles...this is a customised tool which uses groovy as script language. I am thinking if it is good to change this particular value from 1.000000959E9 to 1000000959 ?

Comment: I have changed the way I was retrieving the data. By including to_char(column) so that I still read it in the string format instead of number, This works fine with me.